# yii CButtonColumn in gride view gives error

Tags: php, gridview, yii, controller, cbuttoncolumn

i have a admin page with CGrideView , but when i want to change my button column to add some other buttons gives this error : CButtonColumn and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getId".

admin action :

```
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Block('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if (isset($_GET['Block'])) {
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Block'];
        }

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

admin view :

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'block-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        'content',
        'type',
        'enable',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{view}{update}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'update' => array(
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("update", array("name"=>$data->name))'
                ),
                'view' => array(
                    'url'=>'CController::createUrl("view", array("name"=>$data->name))'
                ),
            ),
        ),
)));
```

Comment: You can create any custom column. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755917/yii-query-data-from-model-to-change-variable-in-layout/31761217#31761217) example

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I have another gideviews in my app i have not problem in those but in this case yii give me that error !

Comment: Can you show error and row?

Comment: i say the error in my question @DanilaGanchar :  CButtonColumn and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getId".

Comment: It is weird. Try this for testing. `'update'=>array(
                'url'=>'$data->name'
            ),
            'view'=>array(
                'url'=>'$data->name'
            ),`. It is working?

Comment: Which line of the error?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar 'update'=>array( 'url'=>'$data->name' ), 'view'=>array( 'url'=>'$data->name' ) it is work ! but i want my url , im really confused where is the problem ? error: framework\base\CComponent.php(266)

Answer (score 1):

solved! the reason is in the :

```
        'view'=>array(
         'url'=>'CController::createUrl("view",array("name"=>$data->name))'
        ),
```

it should be :

```
                'view'=>array(
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("view", array("name"=>$data->name))'
            ),
```

and why ?
because ():
Because Yii::app()->controller it is instance Controller of current application. Controller have property private $_id. CController::createUrl it is just static method. In method createUrl() calls method $this->getId(), but when you call static method instance is not created-@DanilaGanchar .

so in CController::createUrl it can't find the id of controller and for use that i should give it argument like this CController::createUrl("/page/view",array("name"=>$data->name)) i try that now and worked

Comment: Because `Yii::app()->controller` it is instance Controller of current application. Controller have property `private $_id`. `CController::createUrl` it is just static method. In method **createUrl()** calls method **$this->getId()**, but when you call static method instance is not created.

Comment: you are right , so in `CController::createUrl` it can't find the id of controller and  for use that i should give it argument like this `CController::createUrl("/page/view",array("name"=>$data->name))` i try that now and worked . thank you @DanilaGanchar .

Answer (score 0):

The order of elements in `template` must be equal to the order of element in `buttons`. You have `{view}{update}` as the `template`, but you have defined `update` button first! So I think changing `'template'=>'{view}{update}'` into `'template'=>'{update}{view}'` probably can solve your problem.

Comment: Still `CButtonColumn and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getId"` error?

Comment: yes , it solved with a unknown reason !! I say that in below